# Keytool command failure

Tags: keystore

I tried to create a keystore file for my flutter project (on Windows), which is necessary in order to publish the app on the Google Play Store.

On the flutter website they recommend using the following command:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

Below that instruction is some additional information:

---

Note:

The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of Java, which is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run flutter doctor -v and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’. Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with keytool. If your path includes space-separated names, such as Program Files, use platform-appropriate notation for the names. For example, on Mac/Linux use Program\ Files, and on Windows use "Program Files".

The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12.

---

The first command didn't work for me. Thats why I decided follow the steps above.

Here's my flutter doctor -v with the java path:

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Erick\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

And here's the command that should work:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore "c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

Sadly,  that one doesn't work too. I even asked a experienced friend of mine for help, but he had no idea.

Here's what my terminal is telling me after I try to create my keyfile (The projects name is sankofa):

C:\Users\Erick\StudioProjects\sankofa>keytool -genkey -v -keystore "c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
Der Befehl "keytool" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

In English: The "keytool" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you got confused with the notes given in the flutter documentation. To solve this issue,

- Open Command Prompt
- Type flutter doctor -v
- Under Android toolchain you will see Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\jre\bin\java
- Now copy the line of code and do cd C:\Program Files\Android\jre\bin
- Type   keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\*Your Username*\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload

Enter your preferred keystore password and other personal info.
This will give you Key Hash. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, copy c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin and append into environment variable Path, then open new terminal and type `keytool`, if it is successful then you can proceed with what you were doing .. try and let me know

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly it won't work.

Comment: Here are my path variables:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
C:\Users\Erick\AppData\Roaming\npm

And the one you asked me to put in:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Comment: The thing is it worked a few weeks ago. But I copied the code of the project into a new one.Thats why I need to create a new keystore, since I deleted the old one.

Comment: @Molgolaiven when you navigate to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin in the file explorer do see keytool.exe listed?

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. I appreciate your willingness help.

Comment: Open your cmd and change directory to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin, then type keytool.exe, if successful it will display title **Key and Certificate Management Tool** and below it will show the list of commands.... let me know if it worked

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>keytool.exe
Schlüssel- und Zertifikatsverwaltungstool
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>keytool.exe
Schlüssel- und Zertifikatsverwaltungstool

Befehle:

 -certreq            Generiert eine Zertifikatanforderung

Comment: -importkeystore     Importiert einen oder alle Einträge aus einem anderen Keystore
 -keypasswd          Ändert das Schlüsselkennwort eines Eintrags
 -list               Listet die Einträge in einem Keystore auf
 -printcert          Druckt den Content eines Zertifikats
 -printcertreq       Druckt den Content einer Zertifikatanforderung
 -printcrl           Druckt den Content einer CRL-Datei
 -storepasswd        Ändert das Speicherkennwort eines Keystores

Comment: "keytool -command_name -help" für Verwendung von command_name verwenden

Comment: So it is there. But the command wont work lol.

Comment: As of the above text you pasted in here it works, so copy that path and append it to the environment variables. Open new CMD and type keytool, everything will be fine

Comment: I already had the path in my environment variables but with java at the end.

Comment: So know I have:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
and
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java

Comment: Should I delete the java one?

Comment: OMG it works! THANK YOU SO MUCH MY FRIEND. MUCH LOVE TO YOU

Comment: Okay now I get another error. After entering the command and setting the password for the keystore,  it asks me to enter the password for the key itself. So I have to create one I guess? But it always give me an exception - access denied:

Comment: Keytool-Fehler: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool (Zugriff verweigert)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool (Zugriff verweigert)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)

Comment: at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1194)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)

Comment: the thing is I could just enter without typing anything, which would mean that I'm not setting a password for the key right? But even that gives me the same exception....

Comment: So there is a password I dont know of lol

Comment: Okay I did run the command as an admin under cmd. Now it worked. This is where the file is stored. Is that destination ok?

Generieren von Schlüsselpaar (Typ RSA, 2.048 Bit) und selbst signiertem Zertifikat (SHA256withRSA) mit einer Gültigkeit von 10.000 Tagen
        für: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Schlüsselkennwort für <key> eingeben
        (RETURN, wenn identisch mit Keystore-Kennwort):
[c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool wird gesichert]

Comment: I'm sorry for the spam, but this problem is hunting me for weeks lol

Comment: The thing is the file is not a key.jks file which cant be right or?

Comment: Try to fill all field you asked to when you are creating the key, it include country, state, company name etc